# What is the difference between "cluster states" and "graph states"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, definition, quantum-computer, quantum-states

I wonder about the difference between the cluster state and the graph state.

I guess the only difference is the graph of the cluster state is limited to a two-dimensional square lattice

The concept of the cluster state and the graph state can be known here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_state

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_state

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is really a difference, though in general, for "cluster state" people would think of a regular lattice (not only 2D - e.g. 3D cluster states are used for fault-tolerant quantum computation), while for graph state, any graph would work (and there are systems which map to graph states with non-local underlying graphs).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I get the main point, but I have no idea about 'non-local underlying graphs', could you please give me more information?

Comment: Well, something which is not a lattice. E.g., take a square lattice, and then add one extra vertex and connect *every* vertex in the lattice to that vertex. Now any two vertices are at most two edges apart: Quite non-local.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference really. For example Michael Nielsen's review paper discusses this terminology a little bit (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504097):

> Note that the states we have called cluster states are sometimes also known as
> graph states. Originally, the term “cluster state” was introduced by Raussendorf and
> Briegel [28] to refer to the case where the graph G is a two-dimensional square lattice.
> This was the class of states which they showed in [27] could be used as a substrate for
> quantum computation. The term “graph state” originally referred to the family of states
> associated with more general graphs G. This distinction was blurred by the introduction
> of schemes for quantum computing based on Raussendorf and Briegel’s ideas, but using
> different graphs.
> I believe it makes most sense to have a single terminology for the entire class of states,
> and then to specify in any instance what graph is being used (e.g. a two-dimensional
> square lattice with boundary). I suggest using the term “cluster state” for this purpose,
> and will follow this terminology throughout this paper.